# PrestaShop Mail Alert module setting

Tags: prestashop

I have a question regarding the Mail Alert module. It actually sends email regarding order to 4 addresses flawlessly but each one of these addresses doesn't see who else has received the email. I know it doesn't sound like a big problem, since you can always go inside the back in the Advanced parameters and see every email that PS has sent, but, for working needs and to speed up things, we'd like to see that directly into the email (as, for example, when you send an email to multiple addresses and you see all of the in the "cc" field). Is there a workaround to achieve a similar result? It would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in Prestashop (or any other major CMS eCommerce platform as far as I know).

You need custom coding (a module) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your module `ps_emailalerts/ps_emailalerts.php` add in `Mail::Send` after `$id_shop` , `$merchant_mails`

Example in my module line 458 :

```
        Mail::Send(
            $mail_id_lang,
            'new_order',
            sprintf(Mail::l('New order : #%d - %s', $mail_id_lang), $order->id, $order->reference),
            $template_vars,
            $merchant_mail,
            null,
            $configuration['PS_SHOP_EMAIL'],
            $configuration['PS_SHOP_NAME'],
            null,
            null,
            $dir_mail,
            null,
            $id_shop
        );
```

Replace By

```
            Mail::Send(
                $mail_id_lang,
                'new_order',
                sprintf(Mail::l('New order : #%d - %s', $mail_id_lang), $order->id, $order->reference),
                $template_vars,
                $merchant_mail,
                null,
                $configuration['PS_SHOP_EMAIL'],
                $configuration['PS_SHOP_NAME'],
                null,
                null,
                $dir_mail,
                null,
                $id_shop,
                $merchant_mails        
            );
```